# how to use python Django and Spark

Tags: python, django, apache-spark

I am going to start a mock web application development with Python Django, and I would want to use Spark as an integration with my web app. Is it even possible? if yes, how? We can bring data from database to Spark through sparkContext coding, but is there a way to directly integrate my web app to Spark?